# Need help to refactor to an async pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I need a little help refactoring my method and service call to an async pipe.

Here is what I have in my component and service

```js
///// component ///// 
bands: Iband[];

getbands() {
    this.membersService.getbandsForMember(this.member.id).subscribe(response => {
        this.bands = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
  
///// service ///// 
  
getbandsForMember(id: number) {
   return this.http.get<Iband[]>(this.baseUrl + 'members/' + id + '/memberbands');
}
```

Here is what I'm having a little trouble with.
I think I have it right except for the service, not sure how to modify it.

```js
///// component /////
bands$: Observable<Iband[]> ;

getbands() {
  this.membersService.getbandsForMember(this.member.id).subscribe(response => {
      this.bands$ = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}


///// service ///// 
getbandsForMember(id: number) {
  return this.http.get<Iband[]>(this.baseUrl + 'members/' + id + '/memberbands').pipe(
    map((bands: Iband[]) => {
      return bands;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: `map(bands => bands)` is a no-op. And you are assigning the resolved value to the property, not the observable - presumably you're getting a type error (although a [mre] would clarify). Do you just want `this.bands$ = this. membersService.getbandsForMember(this.member.id)`?

Comment: so remove the map()? I assigned the returned value from the method to this.bands$ and I have no errors. Do I still need to remove the map()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The RxJS `map` operator is used to transform the value emitted by the observable. If you're aren't transforming the response, it isn't required.
2. The Angular `async` pipe is supposed to be used with an observable. You're right in defining the type as `bands$: Observable<Iband[]>`. But the subscription isn't required. The `async` pipe will subscribe to the observable.

Service

```js
getbandsForMember(id: number): Observable<Iband[]> {
  return this.http.get<Iband[]>(this.baseUrl + 'members/' + id + '/memberbands');
}
```

Component

```js
bands$: Observable<Iband[]> ;

getbands() {
  this.band$ = this.membersService.getbandsForMember(this.member.id);
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(bands$ | async) as bands">
  <!-- use `bands` emission from the observable -->
  {{ bands | json }}
</ng-container>
```

#### Update: Set member variables in component

You could use either `tap` or `map` operator in the component to do some side-effects when the `async` pipe is triggered in the template. Use `tap` if the incoming doesn't need to be transformed, `map` if not.

Controller

```js
bands$: Observable<Iband[]> ;

getbands() {
  this.band$ = this.membersService.getbandsForMember(this.member.id).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      console.log('got bands in component:', response);
      this.skip = true; // <-- set some variable
      // set some other variables and call some functions
    })
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(bands$ | async) as bands">
  <!-- use `bands` emission from the observable -->
  {{ bands | json }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Quick question - If I want to do a little bit of logic (set 1 or 2 other compnent variables) after getbandsForMember() returns the data, would I just put it in right after the I call the service method? Reason I ask is because, isn't this call async. I would want to wait until the service comes back, so how would I do it after the data is returned? ex. On my profile page I fetch reviews, after the reviews come in, from a user click, I want to update a 'skip' value, so that I don't fetch the same reviews next time.

Comment: @user1186050: You could use `tap` operator in the component to do some effects. I've updated the answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: Hi I'm still having a couple issues and posted a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309977/trouble-converting-values-from-a-subscribe-to-a-async-pipe-in-angular

Comment: @user1186050: From the now deleted answer, I assume you've solved the issue with `(reviews$ | async)?.length`?