# How do I concatenate values returned from an async pipe in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I'm having trouble understanding what to do.

Initially I had a method (that fetched reviews) with this subscribe method below and when the reviews came back to the component they were concatenated to any existing reviews, I've re implemented it with an async pipe, so now I'm just setting the reviews to reviews$, not concatenating them like before, which isn't what I want.

```js
// initial method
reviews: IReview[] = [];
getReviews() {
  this.membersService.getReviews(this.member.id, this.skip)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.reviews = [...this.reviews, ...response];
      this.skip = this.skip + 10;
    });
}
```

Here's my modified method to fetch the reviews, but don't know how to concatenate the results like I was doing before. How would I do it?

FYI - I've also noticed that this getReviews() gets triggered multiple times now. I'm not sure if that is from the pipe or tap method.

```js
reviews$: Observable <IReview[]> ;
getReviews() {
    this.reviews$ = this.membersService.getReviews(this.member.id, this.skip)
    .pipe(
      tap(response => {
        this.skip = this.skip + 10;
      })
    );
```

Comment: I think the async pipe is more for observables subjects but not for subscription

Comment: I've added an answer not tested but I think that `tap` is not returning value this could be why you don't get the value after subscription

Comment: You want to use the scan operator for this to accumulate the responses over time.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example in an answer, one that applies to my scenario?\

Comment: what about concatmap? would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem like below,

- Define a subject to store the reviews. I am using `BehaviourSubject` to set initial value of reviews as an empty array `[]`

```
reviewsSubject$ = BehaviourSubject<IReview[]>([]);
reviews$ = this.reviewsSubject$.asObservable();
```

- Next define a trigger for getting the reviews. The `getReviews()` function will simply trigger the observable by calling the `next()` function on the `Subject`

```js
  triggerSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  trigger$ = this.triggerSubject$.asObservable();
  getReviews = () => this.triggerSubject$.next(null);
```

- Next will be to combine the trigger and the observable to get reviews. I will use `combineLatest` from `rxjs`

```
  newReviews$ = this.membersService.getReviews(this.member.id, this.skip);
  combinedReviews$ = combineLatest([this.newReviews$, this.trigger$]).pipe(
    tap(() => (this.skip = this.skip + 10)),
    tap(([newReviews]) =>
      this.reviewsSubject$.next([...this.reviewsSubject$.value, ...newReviews])
    )
  );
```

- Finally, we subscribe to `combinedReviews$` I will use `async` pipe

In the HTML

```
<button (click)='getReviews()'>Get More Reviews</button>
<ul *ngIf="combinedReviews$ | async">
    <li *ngFor="let review of reviews$ | async">{{ review.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Overally the code will be

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private membersService: MembersService) {}
  skip = 0;
  member = { id: 1 };
  reviewsSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<IReview[]>([]);
  reviews$ = this.reviewsSubject$.asObservable();
  triggerSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  trigger$ = this.triggerSubject$.asObservable();
  getReviews = () => this.triggerSubject$.next(null);
  newReviews$ = this.membersService.getReviews(this.member.id, this.skip);
  combinedReviews$ = combineLatest([this.newReviews$, this.trigger$]).pipe(
    tap(() => (this.skip = this.skip + 10)),
    tap(([newReviews]) =>
      this.reviewsSubject$.next([...this.reviewsSubject$.value, ...newReviews])
    )
  );
}
```

- As noted, there will be no unsubscribing. [See a working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-foghrn)

Comment: HI Owen. Thanks for the time to take to answer my question. Just looking at this code you provided, it seems a little involved from what I initially had and the purpose of me trying to refactor my initial code with an async pipe was to avoid calling unsubscribe. (The advice I'm seeing from online guides on observables). My question to you is, wouldn't it be easier to just unsubscribe using my initial code vs using your code? Just a question from someone who is trying to understand observables better

Comment: My code uses observables but subscribes to the observables using async pipe. With the Since it uses async pipe, you will not need to call unsubscribe

Comment: Hi Owen, I understand it doesn't use unsubscribe, but looking at it, it seems significantly more complicated (more code, more involved) vs unsubscribing. So, would there be any benefit to using your example vs just unsubscribing in the ngondestroy?

Comment: Your solution just seems a little over engineered. ??

Comment: It depends,  let's say you have 100 components, and you are subscribing and unsubscribing, you will have 200 imports, for OnInit and OnDestroy, 100 subscription and 99 unsubscribtion, oops! You forgot to unsubscribe from one of them, and you are having a memory leak, it becomes very difficult to debug. Using async pipe also enables easy implementation of OnPush changeDetection, you may have a look at it, it's all about performance and maintainability of your code